# draw.io: How to change the size of the column in the entity relationship

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I have an entity relationship table. The first entry in the first column is AAAAAAAAA but it is not shown completely, only the half of it. I tried to resize the table, but only the second column gets bigger but not the first one. How do I resize the first column to the size of the first record there?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put the cursor on the corner angle of the column you want to resize.

Comment: It either does not work or I do it wrongly. The container with the text can be resized but it will stretch outside the table.

Answer (score 0):

It's a rectangle inside a rectangle. If you click on a left part, in a formatting panel, tab Disposition, you will see size of the inner rectangle: 30pt. If you click on a right part, in a formatting panel, tab Text, you will see left margin 34 pt. Now increase these values and you're done.